# Function to include all text in <p> tags but exclude the italicized text from that string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website which has quotes and name of those who quoted it, and after narrowing down to the **li** tag which has that quote, I tried using the **get_text()** function but it also includes the italicized text which I don't want

Here is the code which I tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
result = requests.get('https://blog.hubspot.com/sales/famous-quotes')
soup = bs(result.content, 'lxml')
trial = soup.select("div.hsg-featured-snippet li")
print(trial[0].get_text())
```

The output:

```
"The greatest glory in living lies not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall." -Nelson Mandela
```

I want to exclude the 'Nelson Mandela' part.
Is there any way?

Comment: The easiest way: `print(trial[0].text.split(" -")[0])`

Comment: Is the format always the same? If so, you can just extract quoted part from string using simple regex like `r'\"([\w ,!?-\.]+?)\"'`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but I was wondering if there is any BeautifulSoup function which does this instead of string functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the authors by destroying all `<em>` tags using the [`decmopose()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) method:

> `Tag.decompose()` removes a tag from the tree, then completely destroys it and its contents.

---

In your example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

result = requests.get("https://blog.hubspot.com/sales/famous-quotes")
soup = bs(result.content, "lxml")

 # Select all authors, and remove them from the `soup`
for tag in soup.select("div.hsg-featured-snippet li em"):
    tag.decompose()

trial = soup.select("div.hsg-featured-snippet li")
print(trial[0].get_text())
# Or uncomment the following to remove the additional "-"
# print(trial[0].get_text().split("-")[0])
```